# In what way does the lens mount limit the maximum possible aperture of a lens?

Tags: aperture, optics, lens-design, lens-mount, physics

In many answers to questions about different aspects of really large aperture lenses it's pointed out that the lens mount sets a hard limit on the maximum possible aperture of the lenses to that camera (for example [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/19599/21986) and [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/19611/21986)). This may very well be true, but I can't really visualise the reason to it.

As I see it the limitation has to do with the opening physically blocking the light. I've made a drawing to demonstrate this:

[image]

The bottom ray strikes the lens mount and can't get to the sensor. The maximum aperture is in this case limited by the size of the lens mount.

**Introducing a diverging lens**

This shouldn't be a problem though since complex optics (that camera lenses are) can allow the system to converge the light rays in a plane in front of the image plane and then use a diverging (negative) lens to move the plane of focus back to the sensor/film plane without having the light interfering with the walls of the lens mount.

The following drawing uses this diverging lens and by doing so increases the maximum aperture possible despite the fact that the lens mount stays the same:

[image]

This is possible as long as you're not close to the physical hard limit set by refractive index. Very short focal length lenses deal with this problem all the time and I can't believe this is the reason that the lens mount acts as a hard limit of the maximum aperture.

It could also be the fact that the corrective elements required when the aperture gets too large degrades the quality too much or gets too expensive. This does not set a hard limit though, but rather a soft limit due to compromises.

Is there something I've missed? Is there really a hard limit set by the mount regarding the maximum possible aperture of a lens-camera system? If there is a limit, what is causing it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are two hard limits on how fast a lens can be:

**The first is a thermodynamic limit.** If you could make a lens arbitrarily fast, then you could point it to the sun and use it to heat your sensor (not a good idea). If you then get your sensor *hotter* than the surface of the Sun, you are violating the [second law of thermodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_law_of_thermodynamics).

This sets a hard limit at f/0.5, which can be derived from the [conservation of etendue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue#Conservation_of_etendue). Well, technically it's more like T/0.5. You *can* make lenses with f-numbers smaller than 0.5, but they will not be as *fast* as their f-numbers suggest: either they will work only at macro distances (with [“effective” f-numbers](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/43633/1730) larger than 0.5), or they will be so aberrated as to be useless for photography (like some lenses used to focus laser beams, which can only reliably focus a point at infinity on axis).

**The second limit is the mount.** This limits the angle of the light cone hitting the sensor. Your trick of using a diverging element dos *not* work. You certainly get a wider entrance pupil, but then you have a lens combination which has a *longer* focal length than the initial lens. Actually, your trick is very popular: it’s called a “[telephoto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephoto_lens)” design. Bigger lens, same f-number.

If the lens mount allows for a maximum angle α for the light cone, then the fastest lens you can get will have an f-number equal to

$$
\begin{align}
N &= \frac{1}{2\sin\left({\alpha\over 2}\right)} \\
  &= {1\over 2\,\mathrm{NA}}
\end{align}
$$

[where NA is the numerical aperture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_aperture#Numerical_aperture_versus_f-number). This formula also shows the hard limit at 0.5: sin(*α*/2) cannot be larger than 1. Oh, BTW, if you try to derive this formula using small-angle approximations, you will get a tangent instead of a sine. Small-angle approximations are not good for very fast lenses: you should use the [Abbe sine condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abbe_sine_condition) instead.

The same caveat about f-numbers v.s. T-numbers applies to this second limit. [You can get a lens](http://www.nikonweb.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=564) with an f-number smaller than 1/(2×sin(*α*/2)), but it will work as macro-only, and the bellows-corrected f-number will still be larger than the limit.

### Derivation

This section is intended for the mathematically inclined. Feel free to ignore it, as the relevant results are already stated above.

Here I assume that we use a lossless lens (i.e. it conserves luminance) to focus the light of an object of uniform luminance \$L\$ into an image plane. The lens is surrounded by air (index 1), and we look at the light falling on an infinitesimal area \$\mathrm{d}S\$ about, and perpendicular to, the optical axis. This light lies inside a cone of opening \$\alpha\$. We want to compute the illuminance delivered by the lens on \$\mathrm{d}S\$.

In the figure below, the marginal rays, in green, define the light cone with opening α, while the chief rays, in red, define the target area \$\mathrm{d}S\$.

[image: diagram of lens]
<sub>(source: [edgar-bonet.org](http://edgar-bonet.org/misc/lens-speed.png))</sub>

The etendue of the light beam illuminating \$\mathrm{d}S\$ is

$$
\mathrm{d}G = \mathrm{d}S\int\cos\theta\,\mathrm{d}\omega
$$

where \$\mathrm{d}\omega\$ is an infinitesimal solid angle, and the integral is over \$\theta\in[0, \alpha/2]\$. The integral can be computed as

$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}G &= \mathrm{d}S \int 2\pi \cos\theta\sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \mathrm{d}S \int\pi\,\mathrm{d}\!\left(\sin^2\theta\right) \\
&= \mathrm{d}S \,\pi \sin^2\left({\alpha\over 2}\right)
\end{align}$$

The illuminance at the image plane is then

$$
I = L\,\frac{\mathrm{d}G}{\mathrm{d}S} = L\,\pi\sin^2\left({\alpha\over 2}\right)
$$

We may now define the “speed” of the lens as its ability to provide image-plane illuminance for a given object luminance, i.e.

$$
\text{speed} = {I\over L} = \frac{\mathrm{d}G}{\mathrm{d}S} = \pi\sin^2\left({\alpha\over 2}\right)
$$

It is worth noting that this result is quite general, as it does not rely on any assumptions about the imaging qualities of the lens, whether it is focused, aberrated, its optical formula, focal length, f-number, subject distance, etc.

Now I add some extra assumptions that are useful for having a meaningful notion of f-number: I assume that this is a good imaging lens of focal length \$f\$, f-number \$N\$ and entrance pupil diameter \$p = f/N\$. The object is at infinity and the image plane is the focal plane. Then, the infinitesimal area \$\mathrm{d}S\$ on the image plane is conjugated with an infinitesimal portion of the object having a solid-angular size \$\mathrm{d}\Omega = \mathrm{d}S/f^2\$.

Given that the area of the entrance pupil is \$\pi\left({p\over 2}\right)^2 = {\pi\over 4}p^2\$, the etendue can be computed on the object side as

$$\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}G &= \mathrm{d}\Omega\,\frac{\pi p^2}{4} \\
&= \mathrm{d}S\,\frac{\pi p^2}{4f^2} \\
&= \mathrm{d}S\,\frac{\pi}{4N^2}
\end{align}$$

And thus, the speed of the lens is

$$
\text{speed} = {\mathrm{d}G\over \mathrm{d}S} = \frac{\pi}{4N^2}
$$

Equating this with the speed computed on the image side yields

$$\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\frac{\cancel{\pi}}{4N^2} &= \cancel{\pi} \sin^2\left({\alpha\over 2}\right) \\
N^2 &= \frac{1}{4\sin^2\left({\alpha\over 2}\right)} \\
N &= \frac{1}{2\sin\left({\alpha\over 2}\right)}
\end{align}$$

I should insist here on the fact that the last assumptions I made (the lens is a proper imaging lens focused at infinity) are only needed for relating the speed to the f-number. They are *not* needed for relating the speed to sin(*α*/2). Thus, there is *always* a hard limit on how *fast* a lens can be, whereas the f-number is only limited *insofar as* it is a meaningful way of measuring the lens’s speed.

Comment: Great answer, two questions: 1) Do you have a reference for that formula (`N = 1/(2 sin(\alpha/2))`)? 2) What are typical values of \alpha on common camera mounts?

Comment: @Unapiedra: 1) I added a link to a Wikipedia section discussing “numerical aperture versus f-number”, but beware of their formula which has a bogus arctangent, only valid for the thin-lens approximation. Their formula is followed, however, by a useful paragraph explaining why the arctangent should not be there. On the other hand, it is not too difficult to derive the right formula directly from the conservation of etendue.

Comment: @Unapiedra: 2) I do not know. However, if you do an image search for the fastest Nikon (50/1.2) and Canon (50/1.0) lenses, you will see that their rear elements practically fill all the available room. Thus I assume those lenses reach the limits of their respective mounts.

Comment: So what happens when you use a camera mount eyepiece on a telescope?  In astronomy it's all about "brightness", not magnification, and something like the Keck is a huge funnel for light.

Comment: @jdlugosz: Mounting the camera on a telescope is just like mounting it on a supertelephoto: even though the entrance pupil may be huge, most telescopes are not “fast” in the photographic sense, because of their very long focal length. The Keck is f/15 to f/40 depending on choice of secondary mirror. One interesting exception is the [Large Synoptic Survey Telescope](http://www.lsst.org/), specifically designed for [a very large etendue](http://www.lsst.org/lsst/public/tour_observing_strategies), as opposed to the more common design goal of just a large entrance pupil.

Comment: I'm still not grasping it, @EdgarBonet. Can you suggest a URL for more reading? Given some enormous collecting mirror and a desired field, what fails when you put all the collected light on a small sendor?

Comment: @jdlugosz: Your failing to grasp this may be related to your thinking as an astronomer, and gauging the “light gathering power” of a lens by the _total luminous flux_ it can collect from a _pointlike_ source, like a star. This is different from the photographic notion of “speed”, which is related to the image-plane _illuminance_ you get from an _extended_ object of known _luminance_. I already included many links in my answer. I can only suggest googling “etendue” and “luminance”, and trying to grasp what their conservation means. I also added a mathematical derivation.

Comment: The *d* refers to the labeled length, or differentials?

Comment: @jdlugosz: The straight d in dS, dG, dΩ, dω and dθ is for differentials. The slanted _d_ in π _d_ ²/4 is for the pupil diameter. OK, maybe this is not a very good choice... I will replace it with a “p”, like “pupil”.

Answer (score 0):

I think you pretty much answered your own question, there's no hard limit as such.

If you really wanted to, you could have a huge aperture and use corrective lenses to bring everything towards the sensors, but you run into two issues:

- price generally goes up to the square of the size of the glass, having this much would cost a lot
- image quality would suffer.

So theoretically, there's no hard limit, it just becomes very difficult/impractical to create a lens that would actually be purchasable.

Comment: So all of the people claiming that there is a hard limit having anything to do with the lens mount in particular are simply wrong (maybe someone started the rumour and others followed)? Also just to be on the safe side, do you have any sources that can back this up? If this is the case (I need to be sure) there are many answers here on photo.SE that are wrong and unfortunately deserves to be voted down since they are misleading or just wrong.

Comment: No sources as such, but you just need to look at e.g. the canon 50mm f1.2 vs the 50mm f1.8, the 1.2 has a much larger physical aperture (larger than he lens mount) but also costs a bomb and is apparently marginally less sharp than the 1.8. Another example are lenses such as the 600mm f4 which has a (for its size) huge aperture but cost £4k+

Comment: In relation to the above lenses mentioned, it's worth noting that the Canon f/1 aperture is actually large enough to be obscured by the the lens mount when shooting it wide-open on a 5D (or 6D). The 1D has a larger (circular) lens mount to accomodate for the aperture.

Comment: @Lenny151 I'm a bit doubtful to this. Look at the first deagram I draw. The lens element has a larger diameter than the mount even without the diverging lens. Hence both the 50mm f1.2 and the 600mm f4 don't necessarily have to use the negative lens, given that the focal length grants a narrow enought angle of the bent light. Also you cant really draw the conclusion that the 50mm f1.2 is less sharp due to the negative lens, since it could be a result of the large elements and need for corrective elements in general.

Comment: @Hugo I see your point regarding the fact that these lenses don't need a negative lens. Perhaps a better example would have been Carl Zeiss' 40mm f0.33. That combination of focal length and aperture gives a aperture size of 40mm/0.33 = 12cm, certainly larger than most mounts. It is an experimental lens, never meant to be used seriously, but it does demonstrate that there's _technically_ no upper bound on aperture size.

Comment: @Lenny151 That lens is not a good example either. The Carl Zeiss Super-Q-Gigantar 40mm f/0.33 was not a working lens and the focal length and maximum aperture where arbitrarily made up. See this article for more info: http://petapixel.com/2013/08/06/carl-zeiss-super-q-gigantar-40mm-f0-33-the-fastest-lens-ever-made/

Comment: I think "hard limit" is relative to the way camera lenses normally work. You could use multiple stages, making a huge physical aperture produce the desired field of view but end up with the focal plane being far too large; if you use a diffuse glass screen to show the image, you can use another lens behind the screen to reduce it to the sensor size.

Comment: @HampusNilsson All of the EOS series have the same diameter lens mount. The 1D series, the 5D series, the 6D series, as well as all of the APS-C camera have a throat diameter (flange inner diameter) of 54mm. The Nikon F-mount has a throat diameter of 42mm. The Nikon's longer registration distance (46.5mm) vs. the Canon's shorter registration distance (44mm) makes the Nikon angle even narrower compared to the Canon.